# Converting sparse columns to table rows; working with XML with unknown node names

Tags: sql-server, xml

I inherited an application that uses sparse columns. This architecture is causing me a number of headaches. Ultimately my goal is to convert those columns to table rows. Database is on SQL Server 2012.

There are in excess of 8000 columns in the table, and there is a column named 'SpecialPurposeColumns', which I believe is referred to as a 'column set'. That column contains an XML representation of the columns that have data. The data in SpecialPurposeColumns will look something like this:

```
<q7109>2</q7109><q7110>4</q7110><q7111>1</q7111><q7120>4</q7120>
```

These node names correspond to one of the 8000+ columns and for a given record  columns will be represented in the XML only if they contain a value. I never know which columns will represented in the XML, so I never know which node names will be present.

This is probably a no-no, but really there are 2 questions here:

1. How can I iterate over the nodes in SpecialPurposeColumns and get the node name and value? I've looked at a lot of posts regarding parsing XML in SQL and all seem to presume the node names are known.
2. Given that my ultimate goal is to convert this column data to rows, is there a better way than iterating over each row and each of the SpecialPurposeColumns nodes to get these values into another table as rows?

Comment: I would think you could ignore the XML column and just UNPIVOT the data and not keep the rows that are NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (ID int,SpecialPurposeColumns xml)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
(1,'<q7109>2</q7109><q7110>4</q7110><q7111>1</q7111><q7120>4</q7120>')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                     ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                From  SpecialPurposeColumns.nodes('*') xNode(xAttr)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Item    Value
1   q7109   2
1   q7110   4
1   q7111   1
1   q7120   4
```